# issue with Page object and Super class contructor

Tags: ruby, selenium, page-object-gem

I am using ruby selenium webdriver bindings.

I have a class that inherits from a base class and includes PageObject module, also I have a initialize method in the child class which overrides the base class.

However when I create the object, it does not give me the page object property, what is the resolution for that?

Here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'page-object'
require '../pages/BasePage.rb'

class AdminLoginPage < BasePage
 include PageObject


    text_field(:username, :xpath => "//input[@name='username']")
    text_field(:password, :xpath => "//input[@name='password']")
    button(:login, :css => 'div.form-actions button[type = "submit"]')
    link(:url, :link => 'https://dev.herokuapp.com')

     def initialize_page(driver)
       super
     end

    def login_with(username,password)
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        login
    end 


    obj = AdminLoginPage.new(Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)) 
    **obj.username= "test test"
    puts obj.username**

end
```

Here is the o/p :

```
block in text_field': undefined method `text_field_value_set' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is the basePage.rb file? somewhere an object is being instanced to nil when it should be an object which can respond to the test_field_value_set method.

Comment: 1) please tell us which line in your code the stack trace is referring to? 2) Looks like you may be learning ruby from an outdated resource. You don't need the `require 'rubygems'`, the other require is more conventionally written as require '../pages/base_page'. 3) the `**` is confusing; if you meant to comment out those lines, then use Ruby's comment character `#`.  4) Please fix the code indentation.

Comment: require 'page-object'

class BasePage
   include PageObject

      
    def initialize(driver)
      @Driver= driver
    end

    def visit(url)
      @Driver.navigate.to(url)
    end

    def close
      @Driver.close
    end
end



#This code is under project_home/pages/BasePage.rb

Comment: Fixed the code as per the comment.The error occurs at enter_username() when it tries to set 'username' which is a text field 

class AdminLoginPage < BasePage
 include PageObject
    text_field(:username, :xpath => "//input[@name='username']")
    link(:url, :link => 'https://dev.herokuapp.com')
 def initialize(driver)
    super
 end
 def enter_username(username)
           self.username= username
           puts username
        end
    obj = AdminLoginPage.new(Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)) 
    obj.enter_username("test 123")
end